# how to store wordpress loop in array?

Tags: query-posts, array

I am working on a site. This site has a built in layout organize that uses a switch statement to organize data on a page. I want to use that to organize the homepage posts. Right now, there are 4 posts that I have a loop set up to return. Here is the loop I am running

```
query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'homepage', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
global $more;
$more = 0;
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
the_excerpt();
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
```

I need to be able to get the 4 posts returned into this switch

```
$layout = $data['homepage_layout']['enabled'];

    if ( $layout ) :
        foreach ( $layout as $key => $value ) {
            switch ( $key ) {
                case 'block_one' :
                                     //post one would go here
                    break;
                case 'block_two':
                                     //post two would go here and so on....
                    break;
                case 'block_three':
                    break;
                case 'block_four':
                    break;  
            }
                            }
    endif;
```

For the life of me, I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Please _work_ on your older questions. With most you didn't even comment and people invested a lot of time to help you. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I am still new to this site and I have only asked five questions. Do you mean that I need to accept answers bu clicking the checkmark?

Comment: what is the uptick thing suppose to do? The system won't allow me to do that anyway. It says I don't have enough reputation. not sure why you need it but I am sure there must be a reason. I am figuring it out. Slowly

Comment: @kaiser, my mistake; I should have been more clear about good questions and answers, re: the FAQ http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: @songdogtech n/p :) I enjoy having members around, that really care that much about _the system_ as well (like you do). I just have seen some examples, where people just went through their questions in 2mins and randomly accepted stuff... which is even tough for mods to get undone. So, I hope to see you more around here and sry for the bold letters.

Comment: @Jamie The _"uptick thing"_ is the _upvote_ arrow. You can use it when you have 15 reputation points (5 = upvote on question, 10 = upvote on answer, 15 = accepted solution - green check mark, 2 = approved edit/wiki entry). Reputation points a) give you abilities until you're close to what moderators are allowed to do and b) just show your abilities + the help you give people with their problems. Voting up means, that you think an answer is not just "ok", but well explained, formatted and helpful - maybe even beyond the scope of the question. Was that helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use get_posts instead -

You can use the function [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) to get all the posts as array. This function accepts almost all parameters that of query post's.

#### Example -

```
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 3,'category' => 3 );
    $homePost = get_posts( $args );
    $one = $homePost[0]; 
    $two = $homePost[1]; 
    $three = $homePost[2];

    //print_r($one);        // lets see what we have in array - $one

    //e.g. to print the title
    echo $one->post_title;
```

> #### Note -
>
> In this case you'll not be able to use typical Wordpress function's like `the_title()`, `the_excerpt()` etc. You have to manually echo each element of array.
>
> ***Tip** - Do a quick `print_r();` to see what else you have in array and use it.*

Comment: I tried that but couldn't figure it out either

Comment: This is what I was trying to figure out `$args = array( 'numberposts' => 3,'category' => 3 );
 $homePost = get_posts( $args );
 //print_r($homePost[0]); echo $homePosts[0]->the_excerpt;
 $one = $homePost[0];
 $two = $homePost[1];
 $three = $homePost[2];`

Comment: you want to store post-1 in `$var1`, post-2 in `$var2` so on ??

Comment: `echo $one->post_title;` this will echo the post title,
`echo $one->post_excerpt;` will print excerpt if it has.

Comment: Note - to show excerpt - `echo $var->post_excerpt;`, and this will print only if you manually added text to excerpt field in post edit page. `the_excerpt()` function won't be here to calculate excerpt for you.

Comment: I also found that enclosing the print_r function in pre tags made it much easier to read. It formatted the array much better